# How to hide the columns in Table using Jquery Data Table Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery Data Table Plugin.

I tried to use `columnDef` to hide some of the columns, but they still appear.

How can I use `columnDef` to hide some of the columns?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="LabResultDataTableView">  
<table id="TimelineTableTester" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="td-datatable">
        @foreach (var data in Model.ColumnNames)
        {
        <th style="background-color: inherit !important;">@data</th>}
        }
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.columnValuesRowWise.Count; i++)
            {                                  
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var col in Model.columnValuesRowWise[i])
                    {
                     <td>@col</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;    
    ProceduresAndOfficeVisitsDataView = $('#TimelineTableTester').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "stateSave": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "columnDefs": [
           {
               "targets": [0],
               "visible": false,
           },
           {
               "targets": [11],
               "visible": false,

           },
           {
               "targets": [12],
               "visible": false,
           }]

    });

});
```

Comment: Clarified wording.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: Thanks sir for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing you have the syntax error in your code, there is an extra `,` after `"visible": false`.

Second you don't need to specify the column hiding logic for every column separately, you can specify it like

```
"columnDefs": [
           {
               "targets": [0, 11, 12],
               "visible": false
           }
]
```

Third thing `"visible": false` does the trick for column hiding but by any chance if its not happening you can add your custom class for hiding the column like below

```
"columnDefs": [
     {
     "targets": [0, 11, 12],
     "sClass": "dt_col_hide"
   }
]
```

with class definition as

```
.dt_col_hide{
    display: none;
}
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/qef33kox/

Comment: I think defining columns in targets is a great way. You can even change the order of columns if required, just by changing the order in the targets array.

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue then you can accept it by clicking on the green tick.